# linux shell tar unwanted extra directories

Tags: linux, shell, tar

I have the following problem:
I have directorties a/b/c and inside c many text files.
I want to make a .tar.gz file in drectory a/mydir with the c directory inside and then unzip it to that same directory to create a/mydir/c (with all the files inside)

I am at directory a and run: (shell)

~:$ tar -czf mydir/output.tar.gz b/c

~:$ tar -zxf mydir/output.tar.gz -c mydir

but the result is directories a/mydir/b/c (with the files inside)
The problem is I don't want directory b in the middle, just c with all its contents

Comment: What's wrong with `mv b/c . ; rm -r b`?

Comment: the correct tar file is the input for another program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me. Create data

```
mkdir -p a/b/c
echo 42 >  a/b/c/file.dat
```

Archive

```
tar zc -f c.tar.gz  -C a/b c
```

Answer (score 0):

- created a/b/c directories, from directory a kindly try this command.
- so the file under b/c/files were done out.tar.gz
- new directory "mydir" create under "b" and files extracted too.
- out.tar.gz removed from "a".

  # tar -cvzf out.tar.gz b/c/* ; mkdir -p b/mydir ; tar -xvzf out.tar.gz -C b/mydir/ ; rm -rf out.tar.gz

Thanks!